# Laravel Backend and SPA Frontend with Vue (Folder Structure)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, frontend, backend, directory-structure

I want to build a little CMS with Laravel and Vue and i also want to connect it to a SPA Frontend also built with Vue.

I am thinking of separating the two (Frontend and Backend) completely in two different "project folders":

for example:

**BE: *rootFolder/backend/laravel1***

**FE: *rootFolder/frontend/laravel2* or *rootFolder/frontend/vueonly***

I also could keep both in a single project like so:

**BE and FE: *rootFolder/mycmswithlaravelandvue***

I am just curious how you would handle this?

I see some benefits in separating the two. For example I could have a different repository for each and i also could connect the backend to a different tld.

BE: backend.mytld1.com

FE: mytld2.com

Do you think its a good approach or would you just keep the two in one single project like you would normally do?

Thanks

Comment: There is no benefit to joining a Vue and Laravel project together, when you are basically separating the frontend from the backend completely already in logic.

Comment: But there will be some features where users can signup for a frontend user account for example, so the logic is not that separated. I was thinking of Wordpress for example, where the Admin Backend and the Frontend view sit in one folder, thats why i said "like you would normally do". The Frontend will not only be visualisation of data, but has to interact with the backend DB.

Comment: Well it depends on your usecase. You can create that signup logic using simple API endpoints that your frontend calls using AJAX (which reaches the backend). If you're not using Laravel's Blade template files anywhere you should probably separate frontend from backend

Comment: Yes, thats what i thought too. The backend will also act as the API endpoint for the frontend, thats why i thought of separating them in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Use laravel blade templates.